# Footer Items Getting Condensed

Tags: html, css

For some reason the footer items on my page gets condensed and all messed up if you take the browser window and resize it to say 1/2 or 1/4.

Example: http://gyazo.com/c1e8d0f77702d597c10c2a0786711545.png

Link: http://skipq.net/app/index4.php

Footer Code:

```
<footer id='footer'>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="about" style="width:20%;">
      <h1>
        <img width="90" height="90" style="margin-left:130px;" title="This is the icon of app, look for it on your app store!" src="images/iconq.png">
      </h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Available_on_the_App_Store_%28black%29.png" style="margin-left:75px;margin-top:10px;width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a>
      </li><br />
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://www.blog.catblogosphere.com/cb-content/uploads/2013/07/google_play_icon.png" style="margin-left:65px;margin-top:10px;width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="links" style="height:100%;width:20%;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <center>
        <img src="images/thirdicon.png" width="216" height="91">
      <li style="height:100%;width:75%;">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text) > '120'){
            echo substr($text,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="height:100%;width:20%;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <center>
        <img src="images/firsticon.png" width="230" height="90">
      <li style="width:75%;">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text2 = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text2) > '120'){
            echo substr($text2,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text2;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="height:100%;width:20%;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <center>
        <img src="images/Electronics2.png" width="170" height="91">
      <li style="width:75%;">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text2 = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text2) > '120'){
            echo substr($text2,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text2;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
      </li>
    </ul>
<ul class="links" style="positon:relative;float:left;">
      <li>
        <h4>Connect With Us</h4>
        <ul class="external">
          <li class="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-twitter"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.twitter.com/SkipQ">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-facebook"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.facebook.com/SkipQ">Find us on Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/youtube.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Subscribe on Youtube</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/blog.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Read our Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="container secondary">
<br />
</div>
<div class="secondary" style="padding:2px;color:#FFF;background:#1158D4;">
  <ul>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/help">Help</a></li>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
  <li>&copy; 2013 SkipQ</li>
</ul>
</div>


</footer>
```

If you need more code let me know! I would be happy to give more :)

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4vuh/

Comment: No problem just give me a couple minutes :)

Comment: In JSFiddle it shows the actual problem. It only fits at 100% width, when its less than 100% width of the page it won't fit at all and if your screen resolution is low it won't fit either. Its weird because I didn't do the elements by pixel widths, I did them by percentages that add up to 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/v4vuh/

Comment: There are many corrections.. Your CSS is making your code messing up.. Irregular adding of paddings margins.. are making this.. Don't forget to clear the float after the floating elements are completed.

Comment: Just a moment.. I will give you a clear view with some image.

Comment: I'm still looking for help D:

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you have any doubts.. you can ask me.

[image]

Here is your code..

```
<footer id='footer'>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="about" style="width:20%;">
      <h1 style="display:block; text-align:right">
        <img width="90" height="90" style="" title="This is the icon of app, look for it on your app store!" src="images/iconq.png">
      </h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Available_on_the_App_Store_%28black%29.png" style="width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://www.blog.catblogosphere.com/cb-content/uploads/2013/07/google_play_icon.png" style="width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="links" style="position:relative;float:left;">
      <li><img src="images/Electronics2.png" width="170" height="91"></li>
      <li>
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text) > '120'){
            echo substr($text,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="position:relative;float:left;">
      <li><img src="images/Electronics2.png" width="170" height="91"></li>
      <li>
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text2 = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text2) > '120'){
            echo substr($text2,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text2;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="position:relative;float:left;">
      <li><img src="images/Electronics2.png" width="170" height="91"></li>
      <li>
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text2 = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text2) > '120'){
            echo substr($text2,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text2;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="position:relative;float:left;">
      <li>
        <h4>Connect With Us</h4>
        <ul class="external">
          <li class="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-twitter"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.twitter.com/SkipQ">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-facebook"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.facebook.com/SkipQ">Find us on Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/youtube.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Subscribe on Youtube</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/blog.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Read our Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
<div class="container secondary">
</div>
<div class="secondary" style="padding:2px;color:#FFF;background:#1158D4;">
  <ul>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/help">Help</a></li>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
  <li>&copy; 2013 SkipQ</li>
</ul>
</div>
</footer>
```

And this is your css..:

```
#footer .wrapper
        {
            color: #969696;
            background-color: #B3B3B3;
            border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
        }

        #footer *
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #footer li
        {
            list-style: none;
        }

        #footer h1, #footer h2, #footer h3, #footer h4
        {
            color: #5a5a5a;
        }

        #footer div.divider
        {
            border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
        }

        #footer div.about, #footer ul.links
        {
            float: left;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #footer div.about
        {
            width: 330px;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #footer div.about h1
        {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }

        #footer div.about h1 .comma
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #footer div.about h1 .logo
        {
            display: inline-block;
            background: url(/assets/codecademy_logo_smallest-0323fdd409fc100a1991db8aa706f57e.png) no-repeat 0 -2px;
            height: 30px;
            width: 105px;
            margin-right: -5px;
            text-indent: -9999px;
        }

        #footer .secondary ul
        {
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        #footer .secondary select.locales
        {
            top: 15px;
            right: 0;
            width: 120px;
        }

        #footer .about li, #footer .secondary li
        {
            display: block;
            border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
            padding: 0 0px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        #footer .about li:first-child, #footer .secondary li:first-child
        {
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #footer .about li:last-child, #footer .secondary li:last-child
        {
            padding-right: 0;
            border-right: none;
        }

        #footer ul.links
        {
            float: left;
            border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
            padding-right: 0;
        }

        #footer ul.links > li
        {
            display: block;
            padding: 0 0px 0 0;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        #footer ul.links > li h4
        {
            padding: 0 0 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        #footer ul.links > li:last-child
        {
            padding-right: 0;
        }

        #footer .links li li
        {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 0px;
            height: auto;
        }

        #footer .links a, #footer .secondary a
        {
            color: #787878;
        }

        #footer .links a:hover, #footer .links a:hover .arrow, #footer .secondary a:hover, #footer .secondary a:hover .arrow
        {
            color: #005580;
        }

        #footer .links a .arraow, #footer .secondary a .arraow
        {
            margin-right: 5px;
            color: #08c;
        }

        #footer .external li span
        {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        #logo
        {
            background-image: url('images/logo.png');
        }
```

Finally Here is your fiddle..

[Fiddle..](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vuh/1/)

Comment: Hmm...I understand what you mean and I have tried this but what would I actually do code-wise? Just change the elements to float to say the left for example and then for the blue bar underneath just use <div style="clear:both"></div> and then put the blue bar. Not 100% sure what to do although I do understand what you mean.

Comment: This is the output though D: http://gyazo.com/49dcd83aa5b9302b87751c1b12978500.png

Comment: Yaar.. I just changed the code.. for you to understand what should you do.. Don't put your mind only on output.. Kindly go through the code.. So that you will get some idea.. to how to build such pages.. If I have to give you the complete page.. then I have to start from the first.. (Because of messed up css).

Comment: It still has the exact same issue as when I started, what I am trying to do is make it so when you resize you window the content doesn't move, it'll just make that part dissapear.

Comment: if you don't want to move your content.. don't use fluid layout.. go for fixed layout.

Comment: I am already using a fluid layout. I'm going by percentages rather than pixels.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41243/discussion-between-lakshmi-prasanna-and-user2812028)